# View Java Objects in 3D Space

Tags: java, object, jvm

A while ago, I believe I heard of an application that hooked into the JVM and created a live 3D view of sorts. The view showed objects currently in use/in memory, and I think other things like how much memory the particular object was taking up. Has anyone heard of such a program? Was I dreaming?

Answer (score 0):

Was it probably Codecity: http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/wettel/codecity.html ? That's the only one coming to my mind right now.

EDIT: Just realized, that only shows classes and packages, but not the objects in memory. So it likely wasn't that one.

Comment: It isn't the same, but that does look very interesting I might give that a try one day